# Cython - importing cython modules and merging them into single shared object

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to wrap python functions to C++ apis using Cython. I have 2 modules sam1.pyx and sam2.pyx

```
## - sam1.pyx
import sam2
cdef public double calc(double x, double y):
  return sam2.calc_sub(x,y)
```

the contents of the file sam2.py is as follows

```
## - sam2.py
def calc_sub(x, y):
  return x*y
```

with such a structure, the wrapped `sam1.h` along with the corresponding `sam1.so` are generated

During the usage in Cpp application,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Python.h>
#include"sam1.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

  Py_Initialize();

  #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
   initsam1();
  #else
   PyInit_sam1();
  #endif  

  cout << "Starting Program!!"<<endl;

  cout << calc(3, 5);

  Py_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

the `sam2.py` (normal python) is not imported and the error is

```
Exception NameError: "name 'sam2' is not defined" in 'sam1.calc' ignored
```

Could you please let me know what is missing?

Comment: I think that because the function `calc_sub` is cdef then it should be `cimport`ed. (Alternatively, if you make `calc_sub` a standard `def` function then you can probably `import` it). I haven't tried with your code this so it may be a little more complicated.

Comment: I am getting the same error with standard `def` and normal `import`, I have the files uploaded [here](https://github.com/sanjaybharadwaj/cython_example.git)

Comment: If I use `cimport`, the program executes until the point where the function from the other module is referenced, then it throws an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Irrespective of inclusion of `pxd` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1 is that your module initialization function is failing. In Python 3 you need to test the output against NULL, and then print the error (if it occurred):

```
PyObject* m = PyInit_sam1();
if (m==NULL) {
    cout << "Module initialization failed!\n";
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
}
```

(I'm not 100% sure what you do for Python2 since I think it doesn't return anything. Probably just `PyErr_Occurred`). This tells you:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "sam1.pyx", line 2, in init sam1 (sam1.cpp:1094)
>
> import sam2
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sam2'

This traceback hopefully gives you the clue you need - it's not finding `sam2`. This is because the current directory isn't on the path by default for C api programs. You need to set it up so that it is - the following code goes after `Py_Initialize` but before the module initialization:

```
PyObject* path = PySys_GetObject("path");
// append "." to the path
PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethod(path,"append","(s)",".");
Py_XDECREF(result);
// don't decref path though - it's borrowed
```

It gets `sys.path` and appends `.` to it. After that everything works fine.

---

Note - if you call your program from a different directory then "." refers to the wrong place. If this is the case then you need to do something cleverer and work out the fill path to the directory, probably from `argv[0]`.

Comment: The error was exactly what you have mentioned, `path` was not correct. It works for both the cases with `cimport` and `import`, i.e. with and without `pxd` files

Comment: But these informations are not present in the cython documentation or any guides. Is there a guide for this?

Comment: No documentation that I know of I'm afraid. It's a fairly common that people using the Python C API don't check if an error has occurred so it's usually a good place to start. Having got that error message it's then a bit easier to try to diagnose.

Comment: Also is there any way to merge the various `shared object` files generated from every `pyx` file? Now to link the application, every time I need to link all the generated libraries.

Comment: Merging the various shared object files is (close to?) impossible I believe. The Python import mechanism works on the basis that the files will all be separate and will all have an appropriately named init function. Python3 does [define ways to store multiple modules in one library](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0489/#multiple-modules-in-one-library) but Cython hasn't done anything with it.